# xslt 1.0 replace multiple occurences of a string in datapower

Tags: string, xslt, replaceall

Hi am trying to replace few characters in a xml with some values using xsl in datapower. i got few snippets from stackoverflow , but i guess its not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="dp" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="dp" version="1.0" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Output">
        <xsl:copy-of select="dp:variable('var://context/INPUT')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">***  before replace ***<xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/> ***</xsl:message>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Output,'&amp;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Output"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&amp;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'%26amp%3B'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">***  after and***<xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/> ***</xsl:message>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Output,'&gt;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Output"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&gt;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'%26gt%3B'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">*** IsoClaimsearch after gt***<xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/> ***</xsl:message>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Output,'&lt;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Output"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&lt;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'%26lt%3B'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">***  after lt***<xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/> ***</xsl:message>
    <xsl:if test="contains($Output,'&quot;')">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$Output"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'%26quot%3B'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">***  after quot***<xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/> ***</xsl:message>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/>
    <xsl:message dp:priority="debug">***   after replace ***<xsl:copy-of select="$Output"/> ***</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

am not sure what i have missed in this . can somebody please help me

Comment: Please review: [mcve]

Comment: What's not working?